# Relative name to get information from Form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I would like to know if it is possible in a Saved Query on MS Access to use WHERE clause getting value from a Form independent of MS Access installed language?

In a MS SQL QUERY WHERE clause that should be equal to a text in a form, I wrote it like this

```
= Form!Form_name!text_name
```

This work fine if all user have MS English version installed, however, this is not true in my case, as some users have a Portuguese version. In their version, the right way to call the same syntax should be:

```
= Formulários!Form_name!text_name
```

So, the problem is that Access does not recognize this considering language version. Due to this, if a user with Portuguese version try to run the query, it will pop up an insert box.

I've look throughout many sources but none could help me to solve this.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I doubt it. I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build criteria and apply to form or report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this as I don't have a portuguese version of Access but I avoid calls to form parameters because they are brittle.  For instance the form has to be open or the query fails in wierd ways.  If I must use a form's parameter I wrap the parameter in a public function (usually in that forms code behind).  **A public function usually gets picked up by intellisense even in the designer but a public variable does not.**
My style is to synthesize a property with a private global scope variable and public get and set functions.  Then in the designer you can call: get-myforms-property instead of Form!Form_name!text_name.  When the form opens and closes I usually call set-myforms-property and set it to be equal to the actual form property.
    In this way you also get the advantages of wrapping.  For instance you can choose what value to return when the form is closed rather than just having the query fail.